How to use onboard 0.42 inch OLED for ESP32-C3 OLED development board with micropython
I can not get the onboard 0.42 inch OLED display working for a esp32-c3 dev board I bought from aliexpress (https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256807156068355.html). I flashed the micropython rom and everything else is working. Code is below. I connected a separate 128x32 OLED and it works fine the code after I update change the width and height.

The onboard OLED either shows a static like pattern, or full black or white depending on the resolution I try, so it seems the esp32 is communicating with it.
The item description on aliexpress has a cryptic message which I do not know what to do with "This screen is different from Other 0.42 -inch screen. The starting point of the screen is 12864 (13, 14)
Please pay attention before buying, you must not directly replace other 0.42 -inch screens"
I am using ssd1306.py from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stlehmann/micropython-ssd1306/refs/heads/master/ssd1306.py
import machine
import ssd1306

i2c = machine.SoftI2C(scl=machine.Pin(6), sda=machine.Pin(5))

width = 72
height = 40
oled = ssd1306.SSD1306_I2C(width, height, i2c)
oled.fill(0)
oled.text("hello", 0, 0)
oled.text("world!", 10, 10)
oled.text("123", 20, 20)
oled.text("abc", 30, 30)
oled.show()


The aliexpress page linked in the question has a review which contains The OLED is indeed a bit weird, you need a bit of trick to get it working followed by some code. Have you tried the code posted in the review?

That worked! Still having trouble with micropython.

@JeffHernandez Still having trouble with micropython ... please post a new question ... do not be asking at this question

this question is for micropython

I have tried with SH1106 py library and it run well.
My example code in Micropython is:

from machine import Pin, I2C
from sh1106 import SH1106_I2C

WIDTH = 128
HEIGHT = 64

i2c = I2C(0, scl=Pin(6), sda=Pin(5), freq=400000)

print("I2C Address : "+hex(i2c.scan()[0]).upper())
print("I2C Configuration: "+str(i2c))

oled = SH1106_I2C(WIDTH, HEIGHT, i2c)
oled.rotate(1)
oled.fill(0)
oled.contrast(255)
oled.text("12345678",30,12)
oled.text("12345678",30,23)
oled.text("12345678",30,34)
oled.text("12345678",30,45)
oled.show()


I'm sorry for the formatting, but i can't understand how run

In my edit in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/revisions/727111/2 I corrected the formatting, but the subsequent edit removed the code formatting.

Thanks Chester.
I leave the text so now.

The aliexpress page linked in the question has a review which contains:

The OLED is indeed a bit weird, you need a bit of trick to get it working

And is followed by the code:
#include <U8g2lib.h>
#include <Wire.h>

// there is no 72x40 constructor in u8g2 hence the 72x40 screen is mapped in the middle of the 132x64 pixel buffer of the SSD1306 controller
U8G2_SSD1306_128X64_NONAME_F_HW_I2C u8g2(U8G2_R0, U8X8_PIN_NONE, 6, 5);
int width = 72;
int height = 40;
int xOffset = 30; // = (132-w)/2
int yOffset = 12; // = (64-h)/2

void setup(void)
{
     delay(1000);
     u8g2.begin();
     u8g2.setContrast(255); // set contrast to maximum 
     u8g2.setBusClock(400000); //400kHz I2C 
     u8g2.setFont(u8g2_font_ncenB10_tr);
}

void loop(void)
{
    u8g2.clearBuffer(); // clear the internal memory
    u8g2.drawFrame(xOffset+0, yOffset+0, width, height); //draw a frame around the border
    u8g2.setCursor(xOffset+15, yOffset+25);
    u8g2.printf("%dx%d", width, height);
    u8g2.sendBuffer(); // transfer internal memory to the display
}

It looks like the required U8g2lib.h is part of the u8g2 github project. I haven't attempted to compile the above code myself, but the comment indicates the code worked.
The code in the aliexpress review didn't preserve the line endings, so had to format it above to separate the // comments from the statements.
